# Unistalled MySQL 5.6 and installed MySQL 5.7 - Restore Database and Tables

Tags: mysql, restore, disaster-recovery

All of the data resides in "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data".  There are 46 folders inside of this folder.  There is one folder for every old database I had.  For example the first three database are "509", "blog" and "bsp".  Inside each of the folders, named after the database, are several files:

auth_history.frm
auth_hisotry.ibd
comments.frm
comments.ibd
db.opt
familymembers.frm
familymembers.MYD
familymemeber.MYI

etc.

Only three tables show in MySQL Workbench, sakila,sys and world.  These may be databases that come along with a complete install.

I'd like to get the old schemas and data back.  How do I do that?  I've tried several things, but reading binary files is not my strongest point.

***All help is really appreciated.***  Several schemas had hundreds of tables and lots of data.  Nothing is larger than 1/2 Gig.

I'm currently running MySQL 5.7 on a Windows 10 Pro machine.

Comment: Your MySQL server is probably started with an  .ini where the data path is different from where your old files are. check your ini and update the data path.

Answer (score 1):

The "user" that logged into Workbench did not have permissions to see the rest of the databases.

Also, did you run `mysql_upgrade`?